# Move project to another organisation under the same Visual Studio DevOps account

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to move a project from organisation **A** to organisation **B**?
Both organisation are under the same Visual Studio DevOps user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature like this out-of-the-box, there is an open [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te) about it, and Microsoft says:

> We are committed to supporting the ability to move projects between
>   collections, however we’ve been unable to make progress on this
>   feature. Unfortunately, the challenges highlighted in earlier posts
>   are still present.  I don’t foresee us making progress on this feature
>   within the next 6 months. We will provide an update once we start
>   planning for the second half of 2019.

You can use some migration tools, like [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration#) and [OpsHub](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/), but is not full migration (only work items, tets, etc.), each tool has his limitations.

Comment: And what if we only want to migrate the source files / branches / etc... ?

Comment: Do you using GIT or TFVC?

Comment: I am using GIT for my projects

Comment: So it's easy, clone the repo to your PC and in the new organisation import it.

Comment: You're welcome! if you will do not succeed you can update here.